# Changing of Logo when a specific ul li link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a site where client wants the header logo to change based on the category and subcategory links clicked.

So if user is on Kathryn Wilson and its sub cats (shoes, apparel) the Kathryn Wilson Logo will display in kwlogo. When user is on Miss Wilson and its sub cats (shoes, apparel) the Miss Wilson logo will replace in kwlogo.

- Kathryn Wilson

  - Shoes
  - Apparel
- Miss Wilson

  - Shoes
  - Apparel

This is the code i've been working with but can't seem to get it working

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
    if ( $('ul.categorymenulevel li a[title="Kathryn Wilson"]').siblings().size() > 0 ) {
        $('#kwlogo').show();
    }
    else if ( $('ul.categorymenulevel li a[title="Miss Wilson"]').siblings().size() > 0 ) {
        $('#kwlogo').css({
            'background-image' : 'url(/user/files/logo_misswilson.jpg)',
            width : '115px',
            height : '63px',
        });
        $('#kwlogo').attr("href", "/category/miss-wilson/2.aspx")
        $('#kwlogo').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#kwlogo').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Any assistant will be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you considered using PHP and checking the `$_GET[]` of the particular page you are on?

Comment: Can you provide some html code or create a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @bryan sorry are you able to post an example? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user3303786 I would have to see code. Are you using wordpress? is it your own script? What do the links look like?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Can you please try to rephrase it? what do you exactly mean "if the user is on", do you mean he hover the mouse over that menu, or he clicks on it? If this is a menu in the first place.

Comment: @Emil Borconi He clearly starts with "category and subcategory links clicked" so I think he means click! How is this question confusing?

Comment: @J.Rahmati hopefully i've set this right http://jsfiddle.net/muMpT/ thanks for your reply

Comment: That is the title but the description says different,maybe my english is not perfect but being on something is not the same like clicking. Anyway an HTML will be necessary so the question can be answered correctly, and people sometimes do mix thinks up.

Comment: Hi @EmilBorconi i did mention clicking of the link in the first paragraph

"Working on a site where client wants the header logo to change based on the category and subcategory links clicked."

Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user3303786 You did forget to enable the jquery option in your jsfiddle so I changed it, but I don't see where kwlogo is located in your html. Is that something you want to create dynamically by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You could find out what the URL is of the page on load, and then find out if that page has a particular text.

```
var url = document.URL;
```

If `url` has the text "kathryn-wilson", do this.

If the `url` has the text "miss-wilson", do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this code really does not make sense... I'm trying to clean it up for a while now, but kind'a lose the point.

- Where is your kwlogo? by Css it is a div, but you assign href to it.
- You have a href in li's meaning when you click on it, the page will be loaded over, so how do you want to display a new logo when you actually opening a new page...
- if you have static pages for each of the links than in each static page just include the correct image
- if you want dynamic pages, and not to reload the whole page then you shouldn't use a href or if you do use a href than specify a target with an iframe which is unhealthy.
  So with all my best intentions you need to clear up what you want before I can help you.

Ok I did my best to clear it up and to give it some sense, also tried to put in relevant comments, however there is still work to be done, I'm trying to point you in the right direction.

```
$("#leftmenu").on("click","a",function(e){
    // will prevent page load for now.
    e.preventDefault();
    //Instead will load the content into our div called container.
    $("#container").load($(this).attr('href'));

    if ($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')=='cul0')
    {
        $('#kwlogo').css('background-image' , 'url(/user/files/kathryn-wilson.jpg)');           
        $('#kwlogo').attr("href", "/category/miss-wilson/2.aspx")

    }
    else if ($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')=='cul2')
    {
        $('#kwlogo').css('background-image' , 'url(/user/files/logo_misswilson.jpg)');           
        $('#kwlogo').attr("href", "/category/miss-wilson/2.aspx")
    }
});
```

Please see updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chhn3/) for all changes.

Comment: Sorry pretty new to this whole thing so i might of left some things out.

I've included the div where the logo appears

http://jsfiddle.net/muMpT/5/

Thanks

Comment: Not a problem, just really I'm struggling to help you because the situation is not clear. You want to build a menu with UL and LI, this is clear, each menu element will have a link, this is more or less clear. When the user click's on a LI element you want to display a logo, and of course to load the page. Are you loading the page over, or are you loading it in a div container or maybe an iframe?

Comment: Hey all, thanks for you replies but i got some assistance from our developer and got it to work.

Keep up the good work everyone!

Comment: @user3303786 So why don't you post the solution and accept it as the answer? That way this question doesn't remain in the unanswered queue, and so others that might have the same problem later on can see what you did to fix it.